# [Microsoft Graph API v1.0 ]Retrieve id of default contact Folder

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm using Unified API v1.0 and i want to retrieve the id of the main Contact Folder, named **Contacts**.

In the API doc, the ressource `/me/contactFolders` give me exactly what i want for all THE OTHERS contact folders, but i want to retrieve the id of the main Contact Folder, not the others that the user may have created.

Any idea how i could find this information?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is a known issue that is already fixed in /beta but we haven't yet ported it to v2.0.  A workaround is to get v2.0/me/contacts?$top=1 as this returns contacts in default Contacts folder for v2.0, and then get the parentfolderid property of the contact.  So, basically this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=1&$select=parentFolderId
```